# WP_Query loop, does not display special characters in title correctly

Tags: php, wp-query

I am having an issue with a `WP_query` loop (full code below).

Whenever I just run `echo $post->post_title` it prints out the title just nicely.

But if I try to do something like the following: `echo substr($post->post_title,0,1)` it can't display special characters such as `ø æ å`. 
It is as if it *splits* the special character into two - what the?

I am saying it splits it because, if I try to run `echo substr($post->post_title,0,2)` (printing out 2 characters), it prints the character correctly, but only prints one.

Here's my full code for the loop:

```
<?php
$args = array( 
  'orderby'   => 'post_title',
  'order'     => 'ASC',
  'post_type' => 'ord',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
  );
$loop = new WP_query($args);

$mainArray = array_chunk($loop->posts, ceil(count($loop->posts) / 4)); // Array af arrays

foreach ($mainArray as $array) {
$first_letter = '';

  echo "<div class='col ordbog-column'>";
  foreach($array as $post) {
    $current_letter = strtoupper(substr($post->post_title,0,1));

    if($current_letter != $first_letter) {
      echo "<h3 class='letter' id='letter_$current_letter'>$current_letter</h3>";
      $first_letter = $current_letter;
    }

    $html = '<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="ord">'.get_the_title().'</a><br/>';
    echo $html;
  }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

How do I fix this loop so I can correctly display just one letter (regardless of which) as a headline over the content being listed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mb_substr() replace substr function with mb_substr

```
$current_letter = strtoupper(mb_substr($post->post_title,0,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a general PHP problem rather than a WP problem.

Specifically, those characters are multibyte characters, and grabbing the first character via `substr` slices it in half

Instead, try using `mb_substr`

Comment: I thought as much, but wasn't aware that `mb_substr` existed (although I tried plenty `mb_` functions). Thank you!